# audio is not playing just audio package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio, just-audio

i have given every permisson but its not working

```
class MusicPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  MusicPlayer({super.key, this.url});
  String? url;

  @override
  State<MusicPlayer> createState() => _MusicPlayerState();
}

class _MusicPlayerState extends State<MusicPlayer> {
  late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()..setAsset(widget.url!, preload: true);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _audioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.url);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: cAppBar('Music Player'),
        bottomNavigationBar: CBottomNav(
          selected: "2",
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Controls(audioPlayer: _audioPlayer),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class Controls extends StatelessWidget {
  const Controls({Key? key, required this.audioPlayer}) : super(key: key);

  final AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<PlayerState>(
      stream: audioPlayer.playerStateStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final playerState = snapshot.data;
        final processingState = playerState?.processingState;
        final playing = playerState?.playing;

        if (!(playing ?? false)) {
          return IconButton(
              onPressed: audioPlayer.play,
              iconSize: 80,
              color: Colors.black,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow));
        } else if (processingState != ProcessingState.completed) {
          return IconButton(
              onPressed: audioPlayer.pause,
              iconSize: 80,
              color: Colors.black,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.pause));
        }
        return const Icon(
          Icons.play_arrow,
          size: 80,
          color: Colors.black,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:632)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:602)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (Mp3Extractor, FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:92)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1017)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30463):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
E/AudioPlayer(30463): TYPE_SOURCE: None of the available extractors (Mp3Extractor, FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
I/ExoPlayerImpl(30463): Release 2194ae9 [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.1] [HWCOR, COR-AL00, HUAWEI, 28] [goog.exo.core, goog.exo.exoplayer, goog.exo.decoder, goog.exo.datasource, goog.exo.extractor]
E/flutter (30463): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: (0) Source error
E/flutter (30463): #0      AudioPlayer._load (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:850:9)
E/flutter (30463): 
E/flutter (30463): #1      AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1435:28)
E/flutter (30463): 
E/flutter (30463):

I need to know why it is not working.

Comment: dependencies {
    def exoplayer_version = "...specify-version-here...."
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:$exoplayer_version"
} i have used this in dependencies its working now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the content of your URL.
However, if you are retrieving a song from an online source, use the snippet below.

```
_audioPlayer = AudioPlayer.setUrl(widget.url);
```

If you want to play audio from assets, make sure you provide the correct path.